# Azure Boards - Define/Manage Access to Work Item Creation or Modification

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

I am planning to use Azure boards as ALM tool. I need to segregate users who can create Epic, Features or User Story in Azure boards. Team A will consists of business stakeholders and should have access to create Epic, Team B consisting of Product owners should have access to create Features, and Team C consisting of developer should have access to creation and modification of user story.

I have inherited **default agile process** type.
Is it possible to attain this level of permission segregation in Azure Boards?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Please try to exhaust azure documentation and support prior to jump on the "how's to do it" question. This forum is for help you with struggle on problems you arise when trying to solve them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try working on [Area Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#add-an-area-path) This will help you solve your issue definitively

Answer (score 0):

As of this time, however, setting different permissions for different work item types is not supported. Work item permissions can only be assigned at the area level.

As a substitute, you can [create three areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#add-an-area-path), and then, set the ["Edit work items in this node" permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-permissions-access-work-tracking?view=azure-devops#create-child-nodes-modify-work-items-under-an-area-path) for the different groups in each area according to your requirements.

For example, you create three areas and call them "Epic", "Features" and "UserStory".

In "Epic" area, you set Team A's "Edit work items in this node" permission to "Allow" and set the other teams permission to "Deny".

In "Features" area, you set Team B's "Edit work items in this node" permission to "Allow" and set the other teams permission to "Deny".

In "UserStory" area, you set Team C's "Edit work items in this node" permission to "Allow" and set the other teams permission to "Deny".

This allows each team to create and modify work items only in the corresponding area.